# Is it possible to save the gui/widgets created by code at run time?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I would like to save the gui/widgets that my code will create. 
So let say my code creates:

```
   QDialog *mywidget = new QDialog;
   miwidget->addwidget(/some widgtes/);
   mywidget->show();
```

What I want is, let say I have save action in menu/toolbar, 
by calling the action, I would like to save it above QDialog in some location.

And another thing, is it possible to save as Qdesigner .ui file, so I can further load with QFormloader or QGuiloader?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QAbstractFormBuilder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html) class has a [save](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html#save) function that can save widgets to a .ui file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking to write xml generator, It will save a lot time and bugs. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In theory answer is YES. If you have a look into .ui file you will see that it's just an XML file with quite straight forward syntax, containing all children objects with properties etc.

So I don't see any problems to traverse child tree and generate file which will be accepted by UI designer or which you can use later on to load form dynamically through FormFactory.

Comment: So, there is no built method already in Qt to use to save the gui as .ui file? I also thought writing my own xml generator, but as I am not so familiar with Qt, thought there might be something to use.

Comment: if it does not exist, then how can I get widget tree from a window, or should I also read one by one each of the widgets?